# Access violation reading location for file input

Tags: c++

So I am trying to read this 1024 line file with 8 characters in each line, and I am trying to store all that in a 2d character array with each element containing one 8 character string
this is what I have

```
char ch=" ";
char page[1024][9];
while(i!=32767)
{


 ch = fgetc(fp);
 printf("%c",ch);
 i++;

 if(ch==EOF)
 {
   break;
 }
 page[q][p]=ch;

   if (p<7)
    p=p+1;
   else if (p==7)
    {p=0;q=q+1;}


  }
```

I get about 50-100 lines of the 2d array printed in the output but after that it stops and gives me an error. 
Unhandled exception at 0x5f942174 in C1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: This looks like c, not c++. Did you get the difference? Or do you really use a c++ compiler?

Comment: You do not show the initialization of p and q. I suppose they are set to 0 somewhere before starting the loop ? And you talk about 1024 **lines** but I do not see where you skip end of line characters ? Or are you sure there are no other characters to filter from you input ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta: if the "8 characters in each line" includes the newline, then they'll all end up in `page[q][7]` and no special handling is needed.  Bit strange though, and not sure what's meant to be in `page[q][8]`... NUL, or is it not even needed?

Comment: @TonyD It is the first time is see a parser that makes no control on its input, so my comment. But your remark is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing braces around the body of the last `if`; basically your code is identical to

```
if (p<7)
{
    p=p+1;
}
else
{
    p=0;
}
q=q+1;
```

which means that `q` is incremented on every iteration and not only when `p` reaches 7. Change that to

```
if (p<7)
{
    p=p+1;
}
else
{
    p=0;
    q=q+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing braces around the body of the `else if`:

```
else if (p==7) {
    p=0;q=q+1;
}
```

Comment: @user3682467: Where do you skip the line after you read 8 characters of line? You are reading all characters in the file without checking that 8 chars readied or not?

Comment: I have written an if statement which allows me to write 8 characters to every string in the array. I dont know what you mean by checking of 8chars readied or not

Comment: @user3682467: Your code print all characters of your file with 8chars by 8chars.

Comment: @user3682467: Add this line into `else if` statement `while((ch=fgetc(fp))!='\n' && ch!=EOF);` to skip other characters in current line

Comment: The text file has only 8 characters in every line so no code is required for skipping and also I dont know c++ so I cant understand/use the C++ solutions that you may give me.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is this code what you want: **Please read commented code bellow**

```
char ch=' '; // changed ch=" " to ch= ' '
char page[1023][7]; //changed to 1024 line and 8 char.0-1023 and 0-7 indexes
int q=0,p=0;
do {
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    printf("%c",ch);
    page[q][p]=ch;
        p=p+1;
    if (p>7) {
        p=0;
        q=q+1;
    }
} while(ch!=EOF);
```

Comment: @user3682467: Did you get error with this code too?